# Read a SQL table cell value and only change a ComboBox.text without changing the ComboBox collection items

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, combobox

I'm trying to make an army list builder for a miniatures strategy game.

I'd like to know the correct method to read a SQL table cell value and to put it for each unit into a ComboBox.text field, but only into the field.

The ComBoBox collection items should not be modified (I need them to remain as it is). I just want the ComboBox.text value to be modified with the red framed value, and for each unit

For the record, currently, I read the others table informations and load them into the others ComboBoxes this way :

```
Private Sub TextBoxQuantitéUnités_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxQuantitéUnités.Click
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=OST;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim sqlquery As String

        connection.Open()

        sqlquery = "select * from liste1 Order By index_unité"

        Dim SQL As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, connection)
        SQL.Fill(dt)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        ComboBoxNomUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxNomUnités.DisplayMember = "nom_unité"

        ComboBoxTypeUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxTypeUnités.DisplayMember = "type_unité"

        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.DisplayMember = "abréviation_unité"

        ComboBoxCoutTotal.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxCoutTotal.DisplayMember = "cout_unité"

        connection.Close()
    End Sub
```

Many thanks :-)

[The ComboBox.text where I want to load the cell value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msKCF.png)

[The table picture with the framed value I want to load into the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gpbv.png)

[The original ComboBox collection I want to keep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkVBy.png)

**EDIT 2 :**

[My table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDIhv.png)

[Your function call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSQJF.png)

[A short clip of the program in order to understand my problem](https://streamable.com/73ivxo)

As you can see, the function seems good and when I check the ComboBoxQuality text during the execution, it seems good but for some reason, it don't change...

The others Comboboxes are sync as you can see on the upper code.

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT 3:**

The whole code as requested :

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql



Public Class FormOst
    Public Function GetStringFromQuery(ByVal SQLQuery As String) As String
        Dim CN = New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=OST;Integrated Security=True")

        CN.Open()

        Dim StrSql As String = SQLQuery

        Dim cmdReader As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(StrSql, CN)
        cmdReader.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim SdrReader As SqlDataReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        GetStringFromQuery = ""
        Try
            With SdrReader
                If .HasRows Then
                    While .Read
                        If .GetValue(0) Is DBNull.Value Then
                            GetStringFromQuery = ""
                        Else
                            If IsDBNull(.GetValue(0).ToString) Then
                                GetStringFromQuery = ""
                            Else
                                GetStringFromQuery = .GetValue(0).ToString
                            End If
                        End If
                    End While
                End If
            End With
            CN.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(SQLQuery, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        End Try
    End Function




    Private Sub TextBoListeArmées_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxListeArmées.Click
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=OST;Integrated Security=True")

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim sqlquery As String

        connection.Open()

        sqlquery = "select [nom_unité] + ' | ' + [abréviation_unité] as Unité, index_unité, abréviation_unité, type_unité, qualité_unité, cout_unité from liste1 Order By index_unité"

        Dim SQL As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlquery, connection)
        SQL.Fill(dt)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection)

        ComboBoxNomUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxNomUnités.DisplayMember = "Unité"
        ComboBoxNomUnités.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append
        ComboBoxNomUnités.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems

        ComboBoxTypeUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxTypeUnités.DisplayMember = "type_unité"

        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.DisplayMember = "abréviation_unité"

        ComboBoxCoutUnité.DataSource = dt
        ComboBoxCoutUnité.DisplayMember = "cout_unité"

        LabelListeChargéeVisible.Enabled = True
        LabelListeChargée.Visible = True

        connection.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxQuantitéUnités_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBoxQuantitéUnités.KeyPress
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBoxQuantitéUnités_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxQuantitéUnités.TextChanged
        Try
            TextBoxCoutTotal.Text = (Decimal.Parse(TextBoxQuantitéUnités.Text) * Decimal.Parse(ComboBoxCoutUnité.Text)).ToString()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonEffacer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonEffacer.Click
        TextBoxQuantitéUnités.Text = ""
        ComboBoxNomUnités.Text = ""
        ComboBoxTypeUnités.Text = ""
        ComboBoxQualitéUnités.Text = ""
        ComboBoxAbréviationUnités.Text = ""
        ComboBoxCoutUnité.Text = ""
        TextBoxCoutTotal.Text = ""

    End Sub



    Private Sub LabelListeChargéeVisible_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LabelListeChargéeVisible.Tick
        LabelListeChargée.Visible = False
        LabelListeChargéeVisible.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBoxNomUnités_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxNomUnités.SelectionChangeCommitted
        Try
            ''  TextBoxCoutTotal.Text = (Decimal.Parse(ComboBoxCoutUnité.SelectedItem.ToString) * Decimal.Parse(TextBoxQuantitéUnités.Text)).ToString
            ComboBoxQualitéUnités.Text = GetStringFromQuery("SELECT qualité_unité FROM liste1 ORDER BY index_unité")
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function for retrieving your data via sql query

```
Public Function GetStringFromQuery(ByVal SQLQuery As String) As String
   Dim CN  As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=OST;Integrated Security=True")


    CN.Open()

    Dim StrSql As String = SQLQuery

    Dim cmdReader As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(StrSql, CN)
    cmdReader.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    Dim SdrReader As SqlDataReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    'SdrReader = cmdReader.ExecuteReader
    GetStringFromQuery = ""
    Try
        With SdrReader
            If .HasRows Then
                While .Read
                    If .GetValue(0) Is DBNull.Value Then
                        GetStringFromQuery = ""
                    Else
                        If IsDBNull(.GetValue(0).ToString) Then
                            GetStringFromQuery = ""
                        Else
                            GetStringFromQuery = .GetValue(0).ToString
                        End If
                    End If
                End While
            End If
        End With
        CN.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(SQLQuery, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
    End Try
End Function
```

Retrieve data and put into your combo box text

```
ComboBox.Text = GetStringFromQuery("Enter Sql Query here")
```

Comment: Hello Yat Fei Leong and thanks for your swift answer !

Well, maybe I did something wrong but it's not working..

I put the function right after the Public Class Form and I called the function with the following line :

ComboBoxQualitéUnités.Text = GetStringFromQuery("select qualité_unité from liste1 order by index_unité")

but for some reason, it's not working..

(FYI, the function automatically added a Public Property ImporLinkCS as String)

Comment: I've edited the code. You need to change the connection to your own instead of using mine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already did that and it's not working.. 

Comment: If u r using sql server, try use the same sql to query using sql management studio to see it returns any value. It could well be the sql statement problen

Comment: I've edited my first post with new stuff (EDIT 2). The function seems good but for some reason, it don't work.

Comment: Can u share the source a bit?

Comment: Sure, thanks. How do you want to proceed ? Copy Paste in the first topic ?

Comment: I just want to see your first combobox value change event that changes the text value and supposedly changing the other combo value. The program certainly looks simple. I can't believe it can't work.

Comment: Ok thank you :)
I've edited the post with the whole code from now.

Comment: Well, it's working now :)
A big thanks for your patience and skill Yat Fei Leong !

Answer (score 0):

Your sql query problem.
Your query select everything and you suppose to return the UOM that relate to your item

```
 Private Sub ComboBoxNomUnités_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBoxNomUnités.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Try
        Dim Product as string = ComboBoxNomUnités.Text
        ComboBoxQualitéUnités.Text = GetStringFromQuery("SELECT qualité_unité FROM liste1 Where Nom_Unité = '" & Product & "'")
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Working like a charm. A big thank to you ! :-D